# Props correct initially then second render caused them to disappear

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently going through a Codecademy full-stack course, and building one of the React projects.

So far, it has a few components, but these three are causing me bother.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [{ name: 'Hello', artist: 'Hey there', album: 'Woah!', id: 12345 }]
    }
  }
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar />
        <div className="App-playlist">
          <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
          <Playlist />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

SearchResults

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchResults">
                <h2>Results</h2>
                <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

TrackList

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        
        console.log(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
            
                { this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                    <Track 
                        name={track.name}
                        artist={track.artist}
                        album={track.album}  />
                }) }

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Initially, app.js has state called 'searchResults', which is a hard-coded array with an object which has a few properties. This gets passed down to the SearchResults component via a prop called searchResults, and then passed down to TrackList via another prop called 'tracks'.

I then want to map through the passed down prop and render the results on screen.

However, whenever I try to load my app, I'm getting an 'undefined error' when evaluating 'this.props.tracks.map'. Having added console logs, I believe this is because my app renders twice - I.e. there are two console logs in my console.

The first log contains the searchResults state passed down. The second returns 'undefined'.

I've no idea why this is happening, but does anyone know how to resolve this problem and why my props are coming up initially then being reloaded and becoming undefined?

Please let me know if anything is missing or you need clarification!

Comment: It seems to be working fine [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-forked-9o1ck?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Yeah it should be fine! That's what I'm mystified about... It's just returning undefined consistently for the props, and that's why it's erroring out.

Comment: It seems like your TrackList component is being used at more than one place, that could be the source of error